# Get List clickable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[Picture to Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSZWB.png)

So i want to click the element in the red rectangle to browse through all the followers, but i cant get it to click it. This is what i tried but it didnt worked:

```
1#driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('abonniert').click()
2#driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a').click()
3#driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a').click()
```

This is how my "driver" is defined.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/bin/chromedriver")
```

I cant get it to work so i am really open for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is almost correct, you just need to access the first element of the list returned by `find_elements_by_partial_link_text` like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('abonniert')[0].click()
```

However, clicking on the following tab in instagram requires that you be logged in, so there may be additional steps here.

Comment: @eliasxlehner awesome, glad to hear it!